# SMD diode identification

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I cannot seem to find any information for this diode, or for the package.  It is slightly bigger than a mini-MELF and has a repeating number 3 as cathode band. It meters like a normal silicon diode.

Any help would be much appreciated. [image: unidentified diode, with mini-MELF for comparison]

Comment: Try connecting a 1K resistor in series and apply about 6-10V in the reverse direction.

Comment: Forward biased at 20mA, it has a .710 voltage drop, and I don't see an avalanche when reverse biased up to 50V.  It seems like a normal silicon diode.  What I am trying to find is the package, which I cannot identify, and hopefully the part number, so I can closely as possible match the forward current, recovery speed, and reverse voltage specifications.  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe SOD-80 but check the dimensions carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Eureka!  It is a Philips BYD37K  in the discontinued SOD-87 package.